# why my "after insert on" trigger not considering all other inserts after the trigger is created?

Tags: plsql, triggers, sqlplus, database-trigger

Here is the conceptual model:[image]
In the driver table, the totalTripMade attribute are all null, but the trip table contain all the trips the driver made, so I need to create a trigger such that when a record is inserted into trip, the trigger will update the totalTripMade by counting all the trips using the l#

```
create or replace trigger updateTrip
   AFTER INSERT 
     on TRIP
     for each row
      declare
         PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION;
         totalTrips number;
      begin

     UPDATE DRIVER 
     SET TOTALTRIPMADE = (SELECT COUNT(L#) FROM TRIP WHERE L# =:NEW.L#)
     WHERE L#=:NEW.L#;

         SELECT COUNT(L#) into totalTrips FROM TRIP WHERE L# =:NEW.L#;
         DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(:NEW.L# || ' ' || totalTrips);
   commit;
end;
/

SHOW ERRORS;

select * from DRIVER;
--
insert into TRIP values(109, 10001, 'SST005', sysdate );
insert into TRIP values(110, 10001, 'SST005', sysdate );
insert into TRIP values(111, 10001, 'SST005', sysdate );


--
select * from DRIVER;
select * from TRIP;
```

so the driver 10001 has made 27 trips before these 3 insert statement as there are 27 records based on the l# 10001, but after each insert, this code "DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(:NEW.L# || ' ' || totalTrips);" keeps giving me 27 for 3 times, it should be 28, 29 then 30, may I know why is my trigger not counting the records based on the l# correctly in the trip table?

This is the output after running those insert statements:

```
SQL> insert into TRIP values(109, 10001, 'SST005', sysdate );
10001 27

1 row created.

SQL> insert into TRIP values(110, 10001, 'SST005', sysdate );
10001 27

1 row created.

SQL> insert into TRIP values(111, 10001, 'SST005', sysdate );
10001 27

1 row created.
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the mistake is here:

> I need to create a trigger such that when a record is inserted into trip, the trigger will update the totalTripMade by counting all the trips using the l#

I don't thing you do need to create such a trigger.  If you need to count the total number of trips made by a driver, query the trips table directly using something like `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TRIP WHERE L# = <driver_number>`.  It won't slow the database down even if you have a lot of rows, as long as you have an index on the `L#` column.

There are a number of reasons why using a trigger like this isn't a good idea.  Firstly, what happens if you insert multiple rows at the same time?  If you insert 10 rows, should the trigger fire 10 times, or just once at the end?

Also, what happens if you update a row in the `TRIP` table to change the driver number, or delete a row in this table?  Are you handling these cases?

But the single biggest reason why you shouldn't do something like this is that it breaks concurrency.  Suppose a driver has 27 trips recorded in the database.   Suppose that you are attempting to add three trips to this driver, and also someone else is attempting to add three different trips to the same driver *at the same time*.  Neither of you can see each other's trips until you commit, both of you can only see the 27 trips that are already there.  In your session, the trigger would attempt to set the total trips for this driver to 30, because your session can see the 27 existing trips and your three new trips, and in the other person's session, the trigger would also attempt to set the total trips for this driver to 30 as well, because this session sees the 27 existing trips and their three new trips, *but not your three new trips*.  Once you have both committed, the driver then has 33 trips in the database, but their `totalTripsMade` is incorrectly showing as 30.

To answer your question

> may I know why is my trigger not counting the records based on the l# correctly in the trip table?

I'm guessing this is because while working on this trigger you hit an `ORA-04091 table is mutating` error, saw a Google search result for this error that said to use `PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION`, so you added that to your trigger and the error went away.  This pragma causes your trigger to run in an independent session: it can't see the trips you've inserted and so it prints 27 because it can only see the trips that are already there.

Compound triggers are one approach to avoiding `ORA-04091` errors without using `PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION`.  There's an example on using compound triggers [here](http://stevenfeuersteinonplsql.blogspot.com/2016/12/get-rid-of-mutating-table-trigger.html).  However, you will also have to write similar triggers for `UPDATE` and `DELETE`, and compound triggers won't fix the concurrency problem I mentioned above.

However, I recommend getting rid of this trigger (and probably also the `totalTripMade` column in the `DRIVER` table as well). If you need to count the number of trips made by a driver, do this by counting rows in the `TRIP` table.  It may come across as harsh for me to ask you to get rid of your code, but ultimately you are attempting to do something that won't work.  I've seen other questions on StackOverflow where people have attempted to do similar things, so you're not alone in attempting something like this.  At an intuitive level, adding these counts to the table seems like a reasonable thing to want to do.  However, once you get to understand how the database works, you see the flaws in this.